# How can we store bunch of json key values in NSstring ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

```
  source =   {
            Address1 = "3244 W WASHINGTON ST , ";
            Address2 = "";
            City = "ANDERSON     ";
            Name = "<null>";
            PhoneNo = "<null>";
            ProviderId = "<null>";
            ProviderName = "<null>";
            State = IN;
            Zip = "46011-";
        };
```

Hi i am very new for ios and i am integrating my app with services and after getting response from services i am storing above dictionary values like my below code but it's showing exception

please help me how can i store above kay values in one NSstring

### my code:-

```
 NSString *SourceAdrees = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n %@ %@ %@" ,[[[[[dicCurrentIndex valueForKeyPath:@"source"]valueForKey:@"Address1"]valueForKey:@"City"]valueForKey:@"State"]valueForKey:@"Zip"]];

   NSLog(@"SourceAdrees is %@",SourceAdrees);
```

Comment: Don't use valueForKey or valueForKeyPath to fetch values from containers like dictionaries. Those are KVO methods.

Comment: please tell with code i am very new for this ios

Comment: As for your question, I'm not sure what you are asking. You say you are getting an exception, but don't say what it is, or what line it's on.

Comment: i mean i wrote this line "NSString *SourceAdrees" wrong formate please say write formate

Comment: hello i want to write this line at correct formate  NSString *SourceAdrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do the code would look something like this:

```
NSDictionary *sourceDict = dicCurrentIndex[@"source"];
NSString *sourceAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n %@ %@ %@", 
  sourceDict[@"Address1"], 
  sourceDict[@"City"], 
  sourceDict[@"State"], 
  sourceDict[@"Zip"] ];
```

(Variable names should start with a lower-case letter, and the word is "address", not "SourceAdrees")

Comment: Duncan you are very fast for giving answer.Before I tried you posted your answer very quickly.Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show value in one string then there is a method called

> stringByAppending

use that i.e

```
NSString *SourceAdrees=[SourceAdrees stringByAppendingString:[dicCurrentIndex valueForKey: @"Address1"]stringByAppendingString:[dicCurrentIndex valueForKey:@"City"]]];
```

Comment: no what is this showing errors when i paste in my app

Comment: This seems like a poor way to do it. It allocates a whole bunch of temporary strings which then get discarded. It requires a huge, nested set of brackets. Plus you can't create a string and then reference that string inside the declaration like that.